# fibonacci number type

Tags: java, types, fibonacci

I wrote a program which calculates fibonacci numbers. Initially, I couldn't input large numbers because of resource concerns, but now after I have re-written it, it runs at good speeds. However, if I use **ints**, the numbers turn out negative once I input large numbers. I tried using **long**, but they wrap around pretty quickly too.
If you don't know what I mean, then this code should explain it:

```
`System.out.println("The 536th fibonacci number: "fib(536));`
`*The 536th fibonacci number: -8757250051716203595*`
```

Obviously, a negative number makes no sense in this context, so I was wondering how I can make it so it will **always** work- no wrapping around, no matter what.

EDIT: Problem solved!

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public static BigInteger fib(int n)
{
    return fib2h(n,BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ONE);
}


public static BigInteger fibh(int n,BigInteger o,BigInteger p)
{
    if(n==1) return o;
    return fib2h(n-1,p,o.add(p));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!
What I did:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public static BigInteger fib(int n)
{
    return fib2h(n,BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ONE);
}


public static BigInteger fibh(int n,BigInteger o,BigInteger p)
{
    if(n==1) return o;
    return fib2h(n-1,p,o.add(p));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) from java.math.

Answer (score 2):

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) would help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like following (iterative):

```
public static BigInteger fib(int n) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger c;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
         c = a.add(b);
         a = b;
         b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

See more in http://blog.paulvargas.org/numeros-fibonacci/

Comment: I made it recursive so I don't want an iterative solution... `public static long fib(long n)
    {
        fibs=new long[(int)n+1];
        return fibh(n-2)+fibh(n-1);
    }
    
    public static long fibh(long n)
    {
        if(n==1||n==2) return 1;
        else if(fibs[(int)n]==0) {fibs[(int)n]=fibh(n-2)+fibh(n-1); return fibs[(int)n];}
        return fibs[(int)n];
    }`

Comment: The recursive solution can be problematic because it generates an explosion of calls, which can consume a lot of memory. If you want that, try this: `public static BigInteger f(int n) { if (n == 0) return BigInteger.ZERO; if (n == 1) return BigInteger.ONE; return f(n-1).add(f(n-2)); }`

Comment: Paul, I don't have an explosion of calls because I wrote it as pasted below. However, I don't know how to integrate BigInteger into my solution.
`public static int fib(int n)
    {
        return fibh(n,1,1);
    }
`
`public static int fib2h(int n,int o,int p)
    {
        if(n==1) return o;
        return fib2h(n-1,p,o+p);
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

you could use [java.lang.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class